# How to use math type toggle with bmc template

Tags: errors, equations

I am new at LaTeX and I need to convert a docx paper to tex file. I am using bmc template but i am having a problem with the equations. I used math type and used the IEEEtrans and it worked fine however when I use the math type toggle output in the bmc template it doesn't work. The command that is used for equations is

`\begin{eqnarray}` but in IEEE it is `\begin{equation}` ... I tried to look for the different and i used `&=&` as I understood but it is not working. here is an example of the code:

```
Let ${{P}_{INTF}}\triangleq {{G}_{1,3}}{{P}_{1}}$. Similarly, ${{\tilde{P}}_{INTF}}\triangleq {{\tilde{G}}_{1,3}}+{{\tilde{P}}_{1}}$ is then the sum of independent Gaussian random variables and has the following mean and standard deviation:
```

This is a text that has equations. In IEEE template it works fine with

```
\begin{equation}
```

in bmc it is not working and i get this error

```
! Undefined control sequence.

l.345 Let ${{P}_{INTF}}\triangleq
```

I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: `$P_{INTF}\triangleq G_{1,3}P_{1}$` is way simpler! Why all those braces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to deduce much from so small code snippet. However

1. `\triangleq` needs `amssymb`, as in the following example, taken from your code:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
   \begin{document}

   Let ${{P}_{\textrm{INTF}}}\triangleq {{G}_{1,3}}{{P}_{1}}$. 
   Similarly, ${{\tilde{P}}_{\textrm{INTF}}}\triangleq {{\tilde{G}}_{1,3}}+{{\tilde{P}}_{1}}$ 
   is then the sum of independent Gaussian random variables and has the following mean 
   and standard deviation:

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Using `\begin{eqnarray}` etc. is not a good solution in general. `amsmath` package offers better environments. Using `\begin{eqnarray}` instead of `\begin{equation}` is a mistake, because the former is for expressions. Certainly, your should remove ampersands around `=` in `equation` environment.

Comment: Thank you! All i needed was the package you mentioned ... I replaced it with \begin{equation} the previous one was already in the template so I did not know what to do. Now I don't have any errors.